# How to change legend title in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following plot like below. It was created with this command:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 200)), 
                 rating = c(rnorm(200), rnorm(200, mean=.8)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=rating, fill=cond)) + 
geom_density(alpha = .3) +
xlab("NEW RATING TITLE") +
ylab("NEW DENSITY TITLE")
```

Now, I want to modify the *legend title* from **cond** into **NEW LEGEND TITLE**.

So, I just added the following line add the end of the above code:

```
+labs(colour="NEW LEGEND TITLE")
```

But it doesn't work. What's the right way to do it?

[image]

Comment: `labs(fill="xyz")` should do

Comment: @baptiste I've come back to this question numberous times without noticing your comment, could you write it up as an answer?  IMO it's the simplest solution and deserves some recognition

Comment: @User632716 it's already in someone's answer below

Comment: it does not work...

Comment: For those looking for an answer involving plots with multiple `geom_` statements, I recommend the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38485985/1169233, it's the only one that worked for me.

Comment: Just note that for other types of graphs (when you use 'colour' in aes instead of 'fill') the OP question code would already work. 'Colour' is already right and not "fill"! I was going crazy trying all the answers and my solution was in the question! ;)

Comment: Another note as of v3.3.2 -- with continuous data, change the legend title with `guides_colorbar()` to avoid the legend becoming discrete with `guides_legend()`

Answer (score 578, accepted):

This should work:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=rating, fill=cond)) + 
           geom_density(alpha=.3) + 
           xlab("NEW RATING TITLE") + 
           ylab("NEW DENSITY TITLE")
p <- p + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))
```

(or alternatively)

```
p + scale_fill_discrete(name = "New Legend Title")
```

Comment: Another alternative is `p$labels$fill <- "New Legend Title"`

Comment: what is the difference between guides  and scale_fill_discrete

Comment: `p$labels$fill` didn't work for me. With `ggplot2_2.1.0` I use `p$labels$colour <- "New legend title"`

Comment: `p$labels$fill ` is nice but if you are using more than one variable in aesthetic (linetype, color, shape) in aes, you have to change them for each separately.

Comment: Many of the `scale_fill_...` functions can take `name` as one of the parameters. I was able to use: `scale_fill_gradientn(colors = custom_colors, na.value = "transparent", name = "New Legend Title")` in my ggplot chain.

Comment: In `geom_histogram` I need `+ labs(colour = "New Legend Title", fill = "New Legend Title")`

Comment: It worked for me on 2024. Just remember to use the specific type of legend in your case. In my case, which was a "color legend", I had to use: guides(color=guide_legend(title="The New Title"))

Answer (score 453):

I didn't dig in much into this but because you used **fill=cond** in ggplot(),

```
 + labs(color='NEW LEGEND TITLE')
```

might not have worked. However it you replace ***color*** by ***fill***, it works!

```
+ labs(fill='NEW LEGEND TITLE')
```

This worked for me in ggplot2_2.1.0

Comment: I think this is the most striaghtforward answer, it does exactly what OP asks for with one extra line at most

Comment: both color= and fill= should work. This is the "right" answer to the question, IMO

Comment: whether colour of fill would work depends on what "cond" (or group in other cases) is really mapped to. A good explanation could be found in http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Note: in ggplot2 3.0+ this solution didn't work: solved it by `p + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))`

Comment: with a grouping variable (that needs to be a factor), only `labs(color='NEW LEGEND TITLE') ` worked for me

Comment: This also works with `labs(size='NEW LEGEND TITLE')` if you are using `geom_point(aes(size = some_size)) `.

Answer (score 70):

Since you have two densitys I imagine you may be wanting to set your own colours with `scale_fill_manual`.

If so you can do:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,group=c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)))

legend_title <- "OMG My Title"

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill=group)) + geom_density(alpha=.3) +   
    scale_fill_manual(legend_title,values=c("orange","red"))
```

[image]

Comment: It works also with scale_fill_gradient(legend_title)

Answer (score 54):

None of the above code worked for me.

Here's what I found and it worked.

`labs(color = "sale year")`

You can also give a space between the title and the display by adding `\n` at the end.

`labs(color = 'sale year\n")`

Comment: How is this any different than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38938781/570918)?

Comment: Yep, I tried every single example above and this is the only one that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: How would this work given the original post question, it seems that `fill` instead of `color` (or `colour`) is needed? Given the time of the question, it is possible it is `ggplot2` version related.

Comment: @merv The main difference is that this one actually works.

Comment: This is all about how you group your data and create legend based on it. If you use linetype like in ```ggplot(data=df, aes(x=time, y=value, linetype=variable))``` then ```labs(linetype = 'sale year\n")``` will work for you.

Answer (score 25):

Since in your code you used `ggplot(data, fill= cond)` to create the histogram you need to add the legend title by also using "fill" in the label section i.e. `+labs(fill="Title name")`. If you were using a different type of plot where the code was ggplot(data, colour= cond), then you could use `+labs(colour= "Title Name")`. In summary, the lab argument has to match the aes argument.

I have used `+ guides(fill=guide_legend("my awesome title"))` to change the legend title on geom_bar plots but it did not seem to work for geom_point.

Comment: ..., but for `geom_point()`, this works for me: `guides(color=guide_legend("Type:"))`

Comment: @knb, your method works: `guides(color=guide_legend("Score Ranking:"))`

Comment: How is this any different that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38938781/570918)?

Answer (score 10):

There's another very simple answer which can work for some simple graphs.

Just add a call to guide_legend() into your graph.

```
ggplot(...) + ... + guide_legend(title="my awesome title")
```

As shown in the very nice [ggplot docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html).

If that doesn't work, you can more precisely set your guide parameters with a call to [guides](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guides.html):

```
ggplot(...) + ... + guides(fill=guide_legend("my awesome title"))
```

You can also vary the shape/color/size by specifying these parameters for your call to `guides` as well.

Comment: This did not work for me, but `qplot(…) + guides(color=guide_legend(title="sale year"))` worked

Comment: merci @ArnaudA only your option worked for me with the plots generated by the `dyno` trajectory inference package

Answer (score 7):

Alas, none of these solutions worked for me.  I am working with output from brms::conditional_effects()

My solution required:

```
+ labs( fill = "New Title", colour = "New Title", labels = "New Title" )
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using a facet_wrap in my ggplot and none of the suggested solutions worked for me except ArnaudA's solution:

```
qplot(…) + guides(color=guide_legend(title="sale year"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the list (the other options here didn't work for me), you can also use the function update_labels for ggplot:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=rating, fill=cond)) + 
           geom_density(alpha=.3) + 
           xlab("NEW RATING TITLE") + 
           ylab("NEW DENSITY TITLE")
```

```
update_labels(p, list(colour="MY NEW LEGEND TITLE")
```

This will also allow you to change x- and y-axis labels, with separate lines:

```
update_labels(p, list(x="NEW X LABEL",y="NEW Y LABEL")
```

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that  works with me :
 `p + guides(fill=guide_legend("New title")`

Comment: What if you wanted to keep the legend title but change the labels for each item/variable in the legend? For example, how would you change A to Alpha and B to Beta?

Comment: I think if I got you question correct, legend is taken from you dataframe, so In the worst cases you can use map function with new to rename variable of you legend

Comment: would you mind providing a little example of how that script would look to apply the change with the map function https://stackoverflow.com/users/7739509/ayoub-el-majjodi

Comment: Also worked: mutate(cond = recode(cond, "A" = "Alpha", "B" = "Beta")) %>%

Comment: like this, if we want to rename legends in one column:
new_names = {"A":"Alpha", "B":"Beta"}
df['new_legends']= df['old_legend'].map(new_names)
We will have a new column and then choose which one you can use a legend

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to the mix, for when you have changed the colors. This also worked for me in a qplot with two discrete variables:

```
p+ scale_fill_manual(values = Main_parties_color, name = "Main Parties")
```

Answer (score 3):

The way i am going to tell you, will allow you to change the labels of legend, axis, title etc with a single formula and you don't need to use memorise multiple formulas. This will not affect the font style or the design of the labels/ text of titles and axis.

I am giving the complete answer of the question below.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 rating <- c(rnorm(200), rnorm(200, mean=.8))
 cond <-factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 200))
 df <- data.frame(cond,rating 
             )

 k<- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=rating, fill=cond))+ 
 geom_density(alpha = .3) +
 xlab("NEW RATING TITLE") +
 ylab("NEW DENSITY TITLE")

 # to change the cond to a different label
 k$labels$fill="New Legend Title"

 # to change the axis titles
 k$labels$y="Y Axis"
 k$labels$x="X Axis"
 k
```

I have stored the ggplot output in a variable "k". You can name it anything you like. Later I have used

```
k$labels$fill ="New Legend Title"
```

to change the legend. "fill" is used for those labels which shows different colours. If you have labels that shows sizes like 1 point represent 100, other point 200 etc then you can use this code like this-

```
k$labels$size ="Size of points"
```

and it will change that label title.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed there are two ways to change/specify legend.title for ggboxplot():

```
library(ggpubr)

bxp.defaultLegend <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
                               color = "dose", palette = "jco")

# Solution 1, setup legend.title directly in ggboxplot()
bxp.legend <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
                 color = "dose", palette = "jco", legend.title="Dose (mg)")

# Solution 2: Change legend title and appearnace in ggboxplot() using labs() and theme() option:
plot1 <-  bxp.defaultLegend + labs(color = "Dose (mg)") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(color = "blue", size = 10), legend.text = element_text(color = "red"))

ggarrange(list(bxp.legend, bxp.defaultLegend, plot1), nrow = 1, ncol = 3,  common.legend = TRUE)
```

The code is modified based on the [example from GitHub](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/157).

Answer (score 1):

Many people spend a lot of time changing labels, legend labels, titles and the names of the axis because they don't know it is possible to load tables in R that contains spaces `" "`. You can however do this to save time or reduce the size of your code, by specifying the separators when you load a table that is for example delimited with tabs (or any other separator than default or a single space):

```
read.table(sep = '\t')
```

or by using the default loading parameters of the csv format:

```
read.csv()
```

This means you can directly keep the name `"NEW LEGEND TITLE"` as a column name (header) in your original data file to avoid specifying a new legend title in every plot.