# Editing legend (text) labels in ggplot

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, label

I have spent hours looking in the documentation and on StackOverflow, but no solution seems to solve my problem. When using `ggplot` I can't get the right text in the legend, even though it's in my  dataframe. I have tried `scale_colour_manual`, `scale_fill_manual` with different values for `labels=` such as `c("T999", "T888")", "cols"`.

Here is my code:

```
T999 <- runif(10, 100, 200)
T888 <- runif(10, 200, 300)
TY <- runif(10, 20, 30)
df <- data.frame(T999, T888, TY)


ggplot(data = df, aes(x=T999, y=TY, pointtype="T999")) + 
       geom_point(size = 15, colour = "darkblue") + 
       geom_point(data = df, aes(x=T888, y=TY), colour = 'red', size = 10 ) + 
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20), axis.title.x =element_text(size = 20),   axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20)) +
       xlab("Txxx") + ylab("TY [°C]") + labs(title="temperatures", size = 15) + 
       scale_colour_manual(labels = c("T999", "T888"), values = c("darkblue", "red")) +    theme(legend.position="topright")
```

Here is the graphical output of the above code:

[image: graphical output of ggplot code]

Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at [**this tutorial**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) to find out which data format `ggplot` is most happy with (long, not wide), and to get a feeling for the difference between _mapping_ an `aes`thetic to a variable in the `aes` call, vs. _setting_ it outside `aes`. You need to `melt` your data to a long format, and map `colour` (or `fill`) in `aes` to the relevant variable.

Comment: @Henrik Thank you for the Cookbook (in the tutorial link) very helpful !

Answer (score 228, accepted):

The tutorial @Henrik mentioned is an excellent resource for learning how to create plots with the `ggplot2` package.

An example with your data:

```
# transforming the data from wide to long
library(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(df, id = "TY")

# creating a scatterplot
ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x = TY, y = value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_point(size=5) +
  labs(title = "Temperatures\n", x = "TY [°C]", y = "Txxx", color = "Legend Title\n") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("T999", "T888"), values = c("blue", "red")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold", color = "darkgreen"))
```

this results in:

[image]

As mentioned by @[user2739472](/u/2739472) in the comments: If you only want to change the legend text labels and not the colours from ggplot's default palette, you can use `scale_color_hue(labels = c("T999", "T888"))` instead of `scale_color_manual()`.

Comment: @Sathish As you can see, the title of the y-axis is smaller than the title in the x-axis. The different sizes are used to illustrate the possibilities and its consequences. Thus the code used in the answer is correct imo.

Comment: @Sathish Adding to my previous comment: it is certainly an option to do it that way! It's all depends on what you want to achieve ;-)

Answer (score 75):

The legend titles can be labeled by specific *aesthetic*.

This can be achieved using the `guides()` or `labs()` functions from `ggplot2` (more [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guides.html) and [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labs.html)). It allows you to add guide/legend properties using the aesthetic mapping.

Here's an example using the `mtcars` data set and `labs()`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp, size=hp, col=as.factor(cyl), shape=as.factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x="miles per gallon", y="displacement", size="horsepower", 
       col="# of cylinders", shape="# of gears")
```

[image]

Answering the OP's question using `guides()`:

```
# transforming the data from wide to long
require(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(df, id="TY")

# creating a scatterplot
ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x=TY, y=value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_point(size=5) +
  labs(title="Temperatures\n", x="TY [°C]", y="Txxx") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("T999", "T888"), values = c("blue", "red")) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(color=guide_legend("my title"))  # add guide properties by aesthetic
```

[image]

Comment: I disagree on that. When only specifying the title, it is easier to specify it in the `scale_ ..` or `labs` arguments.

Comment: I was commenting on your solution from 15mins ago which added the title to `scale_color_manual(title="...", ...)`. I see you've modified it to reference the color aesthetic in `labs()`. I offer my solution as an alternative.

Comment: As of now, this appears to modify the legend if it is a fill gradient to be more nonsensical.