# Boxplot of 2 groups in R with graphics::boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I have 2 groups of data (top and bottom) that I have been able to make boxplots for separately, but cannot get them to show in the same graph.  I want them side by side for comparison for each gene tested (12 total). So, I would like to have the x-axis labeled with the gene tested, and the y-axis with the ddCt values, with 2 boxplots (1 for the top, 1 for the bottom) for each gene.  I have the code for each one separately that works below:

```
# boxplot of first group
boxplot(Top25[-1], main = "Top Performers Gene Expression Relative to 16S", ylab = "ddCt Values", xlab = "Biofilm Gene", cex.axis = 0.75)

# boxplot of second group 
boxplot(Bottom25 [-1], main = "Bottom Performers Biofilm Gene Expression Relative to 16S", ylab = "ddCt Values", xlab = "Biofilm Gene", cex.axis = 0.75)
```

Any suggestions for what I may try?  I've tried to "melt" them together following another ggplot2 question and got an error saying "object melt was not found".  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grouped boxplot r ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718485/grouped-boxplot-r-ggplot2)

Comment: Sorry that looks awful.  It should be a nice table

Comment: Please edit your post to add the data. and use `dput` if possible

Comment: Essentially, it is the gene tested in each column (12 genes total), with the samples being in the rows.  The top samples are in rows 1-46, and the bottom samples are in rows 47-91.

Comment: `dput(BoundData)`structure(list(Samples = structure(c(2L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 14L, .Label = c("1479-SD5", "1711-SA9", "1712-SB4", "2001-SB6", 
"2028-SD7", "2045-SC1", class = "factor"), icaA = c(22.307, 
19.263, 18.586, 17.55, 17.524, .Names = c("Samples", "icaA", 
"icaB", "icaC", "icaD", "fnbA", "fnbB", "clfA", "clfB", "fib", 
"ebps", "eno", "cna"), row.names = c(NA, 46L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: The dput data was extremely shortened up due to the large output.  BoundData is the dataset with both groups of data in it where i used `cbind` to combine Top25 and Bottom 25.  I also have the unbound and ungrouped data saved as StaphData.

Comment: Please, please, please edit your post instead of commenting...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. The main idea is to use `add = TRUE` to add `boxplot` to an existing plot and specify the horizontal position of boxplot with `at`

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
top = rnorm(40)
bottom = rnorm(40)

#Create Empty Plot
plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(0, 3), ylim = range(c(top, bottom)),
     ann = FALSE, xaxt = "n")

#Add boxplots to existing plot
boxplot(x = top, at = 1, add = TRUE)
boxplot(x = bottom, at = 2, add = TRUE)
axis(1, at = c(1, 2), labels = c("top", "bottom"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Top25 <- data.frame(gene=1:40, exp=rnorm(40, 2))
Bottom25 <- data.frame(gene=41:80, exp=rnorm(40, -2))

boxplot(list(Top25[, -1], Bottom25[, -1]), names=c("Top25", "Bottom25"))
```

[image]

Comment: That works, but I want it to be the gene names where it says Top25 and Bottom 25, with a box plot from the top25 group and the bottom 25 group side by side for comparison.  That's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: You will need to create a reproducible example with a toy dataset and an example of the output you are expecting before I can get a solution to you.

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718485/grouped-boxplot-r-ggplot2

Comment: I'm going through and trying to group my data as they did for care, but as top and bottom.

Comment: I keep getting errors with using melt in ggplot.  Any alternatives out there?