# Adding a legend title in an area chart on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, stacked-area-chart

I am trying to add a legend to the following code in R, gplot2 for a stacked area chart:

```
plot1<-ggplot(data=agegenderdata,
              aes(x=agegenderdata$Year,
                  y=agegenderdata$`Obesity Inpatients`,
                  fill=agegenderdata$`Age Category`))
plot1withGeom <- plot1 + geom_area(aes(colour=agegenderdata$`Age Category`, fill=agegenderdata$`Age Category`)) 

plot1withGeom + labs(x = "Year", y = "Obesity Inpatients", title = "graph" )
```

However, when checking online and trying different methods to change the legend title I have had little luck. Could someone please help.

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot `=` between `title` and `"graph"` in your `labs()`.

Comment: `+ggtitle('graph')`

Comment: It is not necessary to specify the name of the data frame in all of your aesthetics. The first command (`data = agegenderdata`) will do

Comment: Hi, @hpesoj626, thanks for clearing that up. Do you know how i can change the legend title on my graph.

Comment: @Saif, this is most probably answered elsewhere. Add `+ggtitle("title")`. Also, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635662/editing-legend-text-labels-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 0):

To change the title of a legend, use labs and the aesthetic that the legend corresponds to.

For example:

```
labs(fill = 'Title for fill legend')
```