# Change title legend position using guides() without breaking the legend into discrete numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, legend, r-sf

I was wondering if you can help me out with a (probably silly) problem with my code that is driving me nuts. I'm using R and my problems are with the package `sf` + `ggplot2`. Is there anyone out there that can help me?. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209608/changing-the-legend-title-breaks-the-legend-color-in-ggplot2), but the solution is not exactly what I need.

I'm trying to plot a numeric variable on a map using the `sf` package. The variable is numeric and I want the legend to be on a continuous scale. I managed to do that, the problem started when I used the "guides" option to position the title of the legend on top. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(sf)

demo(nc, ask = F, echo = F)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc, aes(fill = BIR74)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 34:36) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

This code produces this map:[image]. You can see that the scale of the Bir74 is continuous. If I use `guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = “top”)`, it will work for placing the title of the legend on top, but the legend label is on a discrete scale now. This is an example

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc, aes(fill = BIR74)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 34:36) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))
```

and this is the map resulting:[image]

What I really want is the legend placed at the bottom with the title on top as in map 2, but with the legend on the scale of map 1.

Any help on how to solve this would be massively appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Try `guide_colorbar` instead of `guide_legend`

Comment: thanks!!! I knew it was something very silly, but somehow I couldn't find the answer. It works!