# How to change the title of common legend in 'grid_arrange_shared_legend'?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend-properties

I'm using the 'grid_arrange_shared_legend' function to plot multiple plots. The legend generated has a title which is how the column in the data frame is named. However, I need to modify it to something else.

```
grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(plots) {
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position="bottom"))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lheight <- sum(legend$height)
  grid.arrange(
    do.call(arrangeGrob, lapply(plots, function(x)
      x + theme(legend.position="none"))),
    legend,
    ncol = 1,
    heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lheight, lheight))
}
```

Comment: change it in the plot, before you grab the grob ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622421/how-to-change-legend-title-in-ggplot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)