# Removing legend name

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a dataframe which is as follows:

```
X       Y      Variable
0.351   4.453  a
0.352   4.423  a
0.353   4.422  a
...     ...    ...
...     ...    ...
...     ...    ...
0.351   5.656  b
0.352   5.431  b
0.353   5.222  b
```

And so on for different variables. I'll keep it short with 2 variables in the example.

I plotted the dataframe and I want a legend which shows the variable names but not the legend title.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$X, y=df$Y, color=df$Variable))+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  labs(x = "x",
       y = "y") +
  theme_bw()
```

This gives a simple but clean graph, with a legend. 
But then I want to change the labels in the legend that shows up, remove the legend title, and change the color of the lines with `scale_color_manual` options. 
I can change the colors but I couldn't manage to do the other things because the legend disappears.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$X, y=df$Y, color=df$Variable))+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  labs(x = "x",
       y = "y") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green","red")
                     breaks=c("a","b")) +
  theme_bw()
```

I know in the last code there is a missing option for the legend title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both answers were useful in their own way, thank you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to alter the legend title and labels. To remove the title completely, you can set `name = NULL`.

```r
# Create data frame
df <- read.table(text = "X       Y      Variable
0.351   4.453  a
0.352   4.423  a
0.353   4.422  a
0.351   5.656  b
0.352   5.431  b
0.353   5.222  b", header = TRUE)

# Load libraries
library(ggplot2)

# Plot results
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$X, y=df$Y, color=df$Variable))+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  labs(x = "x",
       y = "y") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green","red"),
                     breaks=c("a","b"),
                     labels = c("Label one", "Label two"),
                     name = "My Legend Title") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your legend title with `labs(color="")` since the color aes gives your legend the name:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df$X, y=df$Y, color=df$Variable))+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  labs(x = "x",
       y = "y",
       color = NULL) +
  theme_bw()
```

Plot:
[image: your plot without legend name]

---

Also working:

`scale_color_discrete(name = NULL)`

For further information check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622421/how-to-change-legend-title-in-ggplot) here