# Combine "aes" and "manual" scales to create legend in ggplot (two data frames)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'd like to add two scales to a legend: one from a data frame and using "aes" and a second one from another data frame and "manual". I've marked in the code what I think should be modified. Thanks!

1. **Load packages**

   ```
   library(tidyverse)
   library(RColorBrewer)
   ```
2. **Create fake data**

   ```
   dd <- data.frame(Year = rep(2005:2021, 2),
                    Balance = c(rep("Output", 17), rep("Input", 17)),
                    Total = c(runif(17, min = 100, max = 200), 
                              runif(17, min = -99, max = -10)))
   drs <- filter(dd, Year %in% c(2005, 2010, 2015, 2020)) %>%
     arrange(Year, Balance) %>%
     group_by(Year) %>%
     mutate(diff = cumsum(Total)) %>%
     ungroup()
   ```
3. **Build plot I NEED TO INCLUDE THE DOTTED LINE IN THE LEGEND**

   ```
    ggplot() + 
         geom_bar(data = dd,
                  stat = "identity", aes(x = Year, y = Total, fill = Balance)) +
         geom_line(data = filter(drs, Balance == "Output"), 
                   aes(x = Year, y = diff), size = 1) +
         geom_point(data = filter(drs, Balance == "Output"), 
                    aes(x = Year, y = diff), size = 2) +
         scale_fill_brewer(name = "", palette = "Blues") +
         scale_size_manual(name = "Balance2", values = diff) + #Here is where I have issues
         theme_bw() +
         theme(text = element_text(size = 21))
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

You can feed your `geom_line` and `geom_point` aesthetics a colour to map to. Then use `scale_colour_manual` to adjust the colour and name.

```
dd <- data.frame(Year = rep(2005:2021, 2),
                 Balance = c(rep("Output", 17), rep("Input", 17)),
                 Total = c(runif(17, min = 100, max = 200), 
                           runif(17, min = -99, max = -10)))
drs <- filter(dd, Year %in% c(2005, 2010, 2015, 2020)) %>%
  arrange(Year, Balance) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(diff = cumsum(Total)) %>%
  ungroup()


ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = dd,
           stat = "identity", aes(x = Year, y = Total, fill = Balance)) +
  geom_line(data = filter(drs, Balance == "Output"), 
            aes(x = Year, y = diff, colour = Balance), size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = filter(drs, Balance == "Output"), 
             aes(x = Year, y = diff, colour = Balance), size = 2) +
  scale_fill_brewer(name = "", palette = "Blues") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black"), name = "Balance2") + #Here is where I have issues
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 21))
```

Comment: Exactly it! Many thanks! So, I had to identify what line and point had in common, in this case "colour" and then set the value in "scale_colour_manual". Great! :)

Comment: Great! Gets pretty confusing... could probably work in another couple of ways: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622421/how-to-change-legend-title-in-ggplot