# Making one plot with two years

Tags: r, ggplot2

how can I make one graph from different dates? For example I have data from 2019 and 2020 and would like to display the results in one chart only for months. How can I limit data from a given time period? I want to have one line for 2019 year and the second line for 2020 year.

| Date | Microsoft Teams |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-06 | 3 |
| 2019-03-10 | 10 |
| 2019-06-09 | 15 |
| 2019-12-29 | 10 |
| 2020-01-06 | 25 |
| 2020-03-10 | 35 |
| 2020-06-09 | 43 |
| 2020-12-29 | 39 |

[image]

On this graph I want to make another line for year 2020. For this I use this command:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data=trendy, aes(x=date, y=`Microsoft Teams`), color="blue") 
+ labs(title="Popularność wyszukiwania hasła Microsoft Teams", x="Data", y="Popularność", caption = "") 
+ scale_x_date(date_labels = "%B", limit=c(as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-12-31")))
```

Can someone help me if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which one do you prefer, but here are two options for you.

### manipulate data

```
trendy <- data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
         year = year(Date),
         date = paste('2000', month(Date), day(Date), sep = '-'),
         date = as.Date(date))
```

### plot 1

```
ggplot(data=trendy, aes(x=Date, y=`Microsoft Teams`, color = year)) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(title="Popularność wyszukiwania hasła Microsoft Teams", x="Data", y="Popularność", caption = "") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%B") +
  theme_bw()
```

### plot 2

```
ggplot(data=trendy, aes(x=date, y=`Microsoft Teams`, color = factor(year))) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(title="Popularność wyszukiwania hasła Microsoft Teams", x="Data", y="Popularność", caption = "") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%B") +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: And how can I change the name of legend for years?

Comment: @AdrianJaczyński see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622421/how-to-change-legend-title-in-ggplot

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

Preparing the data:

```
dat <- tribble(~Date,   ~Teams,
"2019-01-06",   3,
"2019-03-10",   10,
"2019-06-09",   15,
"2019-12-29",   10,
"2020-01-06",   25,
"2020-03-10",   35,
"2020-06-09",   43,
"2020-12-29",   39)

dat <- mutate(dat, Date = parse_date(Date))
```

The trick is to separate the dates into years and months, and then map years as the colour dimension in the chart:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(years = as.character(year(Date)), months = month(Date, label = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = months, y = Teams, colour = years, group = years)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: How can I divide it into days and months? I did not specify the question, and I have a total of data, e.g. for 4 days from a given month, and at this point the chart rounds up the data only for a given month.

Comment: I would change the date variable to put them all in the same year, and set the x axis to that new variable. The colour mapping will then differentiate across the years.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `lubridate` package `ymd` to extract year and month from date with `month`, `year` and
2. Make both factor with `as.factor`
3. Then plot with  `ggplot`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(year = as.factor(year(ymd(Date))),
         month = as.factor(month(Date))
         )

ggplot(df1, aes(x = month, y = Microsoft.Teams, colour = year, group=year)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

[image]