# Issue in changing the legend title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below

```
d1_5<-structure(list(conm = c("Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", 
"Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", 
"Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", 
"Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", 
"Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc", "Tesla Inc"), datadate = structure(c(14974, 
14974, 15339, 15339, 15705, 15705, 16070, 16070, 16435, 16435, 
16800, 16800, 17166, 17166, 17531, 17531, 17896, 17896, 18261, 
18261, 18627, 18627), label = "Data Date", format.stata = "%td", class = "Date"), 
    fin_var = c("mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", 
    "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", 
    "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", 
    "sale", "mkt_val", "sale", "mkt_val", "sale"), fin_value = c(2481.43666, 
    116.744, 2867.10984, 204.242, 3635.91063, 413.256, 17964.381609, 
    2013.496, 27698.71899, 3198.356, 30769.76202, 4046.025, 30816.66228, 
    7000.132, 51608.7533, 11758.751, 56750.72, 21461.268, 74044.41, 
    24578, 658390.11, 31536)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

and Im trying to change the legend title with the code below based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622421/how-to-change-legend-title-in-ggplot) without result:

```
p<-ggplot(d1_5, aes(x=datadate, y=fin_value, group=fin_var)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=fin_var))+
  geom_point(aes(color=fin_var))+
  ylab("") + xlab("Date")+
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  scale_y_continuous( labels=scales::dollar_format())
p + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))
```

Comment: Try:  p + labs(color="New legend title")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting it for the wrong aesthetic. Try `color` instead of `fill`:

```
ggplot(d1_5, aes(x=datadate, y=fin_value, group=fin_var)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=fin_var))+
  geom_point(aes(color=fin_var))+
  ylab("") + xlab("Date")+
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  scale_y_continuous( labels=scales::dollar_format()) + 
  labs(color = "New Legend Title")
# + guides(color = guide_legend(title = "New Legend Title")) # also works
```