# Changing legend title in ggplot changes the shown legend aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I make some plot with ggplot2 like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col= col)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Okay]

Everything is good but as soon I set another legend title as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622421/how-to-change-legend-title-in-ggplot), the continuous colour gradient changes to some points in the legend:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col= col)) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(col= guide_legend(title= "Some title"))
```

[image: Why]

How can I change just the title not the eastethic in the legend?

Data used here:

```
df <- data.frame(x= 1:10, y= 1:10, col= rnorm(10))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need `guide_colourbar` instead of `guide_legend`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col = col)) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(col = guide_colourbar(title = "Some title"))
```

[image]

Though personally, I would normally just change the label of the color aesthetic:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col = col)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(color = "Some title")
```

Which gives the same result with fewer keystrokes.